# Get all mounted controller collections/providers in Silex

Tags: php, silex

Is there a way to obtain all the mounted controller collections/providers in Silex?

So when I have something like:

```
$app->mount("/faq", new FaqControllerProvider());
$app->mount("/", new HomepageControllerProvider());
```

I can easily get all `mount`-ed controller collections/providers in the last mounted controller (HomepageControllerProvider).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Silex does not hold references to the controller providers. You can access the `RouteCollection` through the `routes` service.

If you really need to get access to that information, you could create a decorator for the `Application` that wraps around the actual app, captures the calls to `mount` and gives you access to that information.

Comment: That's what I had in mind, thought there maybe was a simpler solution. Thanks, keep up the good work with Silex :].